# Realizar un pdf

Tags: php, mysql

Hola buenas quisiera realizar un pdf podiendo la sentencia where que se rellene con un post pero me da error y no se porque, la libreria que uso es TCPDF

```
$usuario = 'SELECT
  divisiones.start_date AS Fecha_Inicio,
  divisiones.tipo_liga AS Tipo_de_liga, 
  divisiones.zona_delegado AS Delegado, 
  divisiones.id_eq1 AS Equipo_1,
  eq1.name_eq AS Nombre_E1,
  divisiones.id_eq2 AS Equipo_2, 
  eq2.name_eq AS Nombre_E2,
  divisiones.id_eq3 AS Equipo_3, 
  eq3.name_eq AS Nombre_E3,
  divisiones.id_eq4 AS Equipo_4, 
  eq4.name_eq AS Nombre_E4,
  divisiones.id_eq5 AS Equipo_5, 
  eq5.name_eq AS Nombre_E5,
  divisiones.id_eq6 AS Equipo_6, 
  eq6.name_eq AS Nombre_E6,
  divisiones.id_eq7 AS Equipo_7, 
  eq7.name_eq AS Nombre_E7,
  divisiones.id_eq8 AS Equipo_8, 
  eq8.name_eq AS Nombre_E8,
  divisiones.id_eq9 AS Equipo_9,
  eq9.name_eq AS Nombre_E9,
  divisiones.id_eq10 AS Equipo_10,
  eq10.name_eq AS Nombre_E10

  FROM divisiones

  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq1
    ON divisiones.id_eq1 = eq1.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq2
    ON divisiones.id_eq2 = eq2.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq3
    ON divisiones.id_eq3 = eq3.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq4
    ON divisiones.id_eq4 = eq4.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq5
    ON divisiones.id_eq5 = eq5.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq6
    ON divisiones.id_eq6 = eq6.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq7
    ON divisiones.id_eq7 = eq7.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq8
    ON divisiones.id_eq8 = eq8.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq9
    ON divisiones.id_eq9 = eq9.id_eq
  INNER JOIN equipos AS eq10
    ON divisiones.id_eq10 = eq10.id_eq;';
```

Comment: Hola Alberto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No está muy claro lo que te sucede o lo que pides... Puedes explicar mejor? Mira [ask] y [mcve] para aprender a hacer preguntas de calidad. Añde ejemplos de datos, los que quieres conseguir con la query, qué errrores te da... Un saludo.

Comment: Intenta explicar mejor tu problema y añade el error que obtienes. Por otro lado viendo esa consulta es posible que tengas una base de datos mal diseñada.